# JAVA read text files, count numbers and write it to Jtable

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

I am still learning JAVA and have been trying to find a solution for my program for a few days, but I haven't gotten it fixed yet.

I have many text files (my program saves). The files look like this:

```
text (tab) number (tab) number (tab)...
text (tab) number (tab) number (tab)...
```

(tab) means that there is tabulation mark,
text means that is text (string),
number means that there is number (integer).

number of files can be from 1 up to 32 and file with names like: january1; january2; january3...

I need to read all of those files (ignore strings) and sum only numbers like so:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    counter=counter+1;
    String[] info = line.split("\\s+");

    for(int j = 2; j < 8; j++) {

        int num = Integer.parseInt(info[j]);
        data[j][counter]=data[j][counter]+num;

    }

};
```

Simply I want sum all that "tables" to array of arrays (or to any similar kind of variable) and then display it as table. If someone knows any solution or can link any similar calculation, that would be awesome!

Comment: *"If someone knows any solution"*  Write code. *"..or can link any similar calculation.."*  OT for SO.

Comment: Break the problem down.  You need to read files.  Start by reading one, see [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details.  Once you've figured that out, you need to figure out how to list files which meet a required pattern, something the [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) can do. You then need to decide how to manage the data, but there's not enough context to answer that, but maybe a `Map` of `List` would help

Comment: And finally, you need to put all of the into a `JTable` , see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.  So, really, you're asking four questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I see it, you have four questions you need answered, this goes against the site etiquette of asking A question, but will give it a shot

1. How to list a series of files, presumably using some kind of filter
2. How to read a file and process the data in some meaningful way
3. How to manage the data in data structure
4. Show the data in a `JTable`.

## Listing files

Probably the simplest way to list files is to use [`File#list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) and pass a `FileFilter` which meets your needs

```
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("janurary");
    }
});
```

Now, I'd write a method which took a `File` object representing the directory you want to list and a `FileFilter` to use to search it...

```
public File[] listFiles(File dir, FileFilter filter) throws IOException {
    if (dir.exists()) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            return dir.listFiles(filter);
        } else {
            throw new IOException(dir + " is not a valid directory");
        }
    } else {
            throw new IOException(dir + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

This way you could search for a number of different set of files based on different `FileFilter`s.

Of course, you could also use the newer [`Paths/Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) API to find files as well

## Reading files...

Reading multiple files comes down to the same thing, reading a single file...

```
// BufferedReader has a nice readline method which makes
// it easier to read text with.  You could use a Scanner
// but I prefer BufferedReader, but that's me...
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("...")))) {
    String line = null;
    // Read each line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Split the line into individual parts, on the <tab> character
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        int sum = 0;
        // Staring from the first number, sum the line...
        for (int index = 1; index < parts.length; index++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(parts[index].trim());
        }
        // Store the key/value pairs together some how
    }
}
```

Now, we need some way to store the results of the calculations...

Have a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details

## Managing the data

Now, there are any number of ways you could do this, but since the amount of data is variable, you want a data structure that can grow dynamically.

My first thought would be to use a `Map`, but this assumes you want to combining rows with the same name, otherwise you should just us a `List` within a `List`, where the outer `List` represents the rows and the `Inner` list represents the column values...

```
Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>(25);
File[] files = listFiles(someDir, januraryFilter);
for (File file : files {
    readFile(file, data);
}
```

Where `readFile` is basically the code from before

```
protected void readData(File file, Map<String, Integer> data) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = null;
        // Read each line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //...
            // Store the key/value pairs together some how
            String name = parts[0];
            if (data.containsKey(name)) {
                int previous = data.get(name);
                sum += previous;
            }
            data.put(name, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

## Showing the data

And finally, we need to show the data.  You could simply use a `DefaultTableModel`, but you already have the data in structure, why not re-use it with a custom `TableModel`

```
public class SummaryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private Map<String, Integer> data;
    private List<String> keyMap;

    public SummaryTableModel(Map<String, Integer> data) {
        this.data = new HashMap<>(data);
        keyMap = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Class type = Object.class;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                type = String.class;
                break;
            case 1:
                type = Integer.class;
                break;
        }
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = keyMap.get(rowIndex);
                break;
            case 1:
                String key = keyMap.get(rowIndex);
                value = data.get(key);
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

Then you would simply apply it to a `JTable`...

```
add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new SummaryTableModel(data)));
```

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

## Conclusion

There are a lot of assumptions that have to be made which are missing from the context of the question; does the order of the files matter?  Do you care about duplicate entries?

So it becomes near impossible to provide a single "answer" which will solve all of your problems

Comment: I just do not provided all of my code. These are very nice examples. Yes @MadProgrammer I wanted sum same rows each by each from all files. Main problem for me was reading all those files, and writing it from store, cause there was problem with empty fields, if one exist stored data value becomes null and I couldn't write it to my Jtable. Well these are very nice examples, I hope it will help for others too.

Answer (score 1):

I took all the `january1 january2...` files from the location and used your same function to calculate the value to be stored.

Then I created a table with two headers, `Day` and `Number`. Then just added rows according to the values generated.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
String line;

model.addColumn("Day");
model.addColumn("Number");
BufferedReader br = null;
model.addRow(new Object[]{"a","b"});

for(int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
{
try {

    String sCurrentLine;
    String filename = "january"+i;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\january"+i+".txt"));
    int counter = 0;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        counter=counter+1;
        String[] info = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 2; j < 8; j++) {

            int num = Integer.parseInt(info[j]);
            sum += num;

        }
        model.addRow(new Object[]{filename, sum+""});

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(300, 300);
f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"Try this:"* - Why should they?  What benefits does your approach have over others?

Comment: I was the first, "other" never existed then.

Comment: So?  There are going to be other people providing there own answer, dropping a code slab on the OP does nothing to educate them or provide them with the skills they need to learn to identify good or bad examples.  The OP has no trust relationship with, so why should they believe you against the rest of the internet?

Comment: It is upto him to believe or not, he goes through my code and if and only if he feels it is good he would choose to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Labled Loop and Try-Catch. Below piece adds all number in a line.

You could get some hint from here:

```
String line = "text 1   2   3   4   del";
String splitLine[] = line.split("\t");
int sumLine = 0;
int i = 0;

contSum: for (; i < splitLine.length; i++) {
    try {
        sumLine += Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue contSum;
    }
}
System.out.println(sumLine);
```

Comment: Using `Exception` as logic control is a bad design/pattern

Comment: There really isn't any.  From the question, we know that the data is in `String|Integer|...` format, so you could simply skip the first element, any value which isn't a number should trigger an exception, as that's what it is

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using vectors . in this example directories will be searched for ".txt" files and added to the JTable.

The `doIt` method will take in the folder where your text files are located. 
this will then with recursion, look for files in folders. 
each file found will be split and added following you example file.

```
public class FileFolderReader
{
  private Vector<Vector> rows = new Vector<Vector>();


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    FileFolderReader fileFolderReader = new FileFolderReader();
    fileFolderReader.doIt("D:\\folderoffiles");

  }

  private void doIt(String path)
  {
    System.out.println(findFile(new File(path)) + " in total");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    columnNames.addElement("File Name");
    columnNames.addElement("Size");

    JTable table = new JTable(rows, columnNames);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private int findFile(File file)
  {
    int totalPerFile = 0;
    int total = 0;
    File[] list = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName)
      {
        return fileName.endsWith(".txt");
      }
    });
    if (list != null)
      for (File textFile : list)
      {
        if (textFile.isDirectory())
        {
          total = findFile(textFile);
        }
        else
        {
          totalPerFile = scanFile(textFile);
          System.out.println(totalPerFile + " in " + textFile.getName());
          Vector<String> rowItem = new Vector<String>();
          rowItem.addElement(textFile.getName());
          rowItem.addElement(Integer.toString(totalPerFile));
          rows.addElement(rowItem);
          total = total + totalPerFile;
        }
      }
    return total;
  }

  public int scanFile(File file)
  {
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try
    {
      scanner = new Scanner(file);

      while (scanner.hasNextLine())
      {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] info = line.split("\\s+");
        int count = 1;
        for (String stingInt : info)
        {
          if (count != 1)
          {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(stingInt);
          }
          count++;
        }
      }
      scanner.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      // you will need to handle this
      // don't do this !
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Start your UI from within the context of the EDT and consider using [`JFrame#pack`] of `setSize`